# Error in mysql trigger code when inserting an if

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to make a trigger that takes the values from the table `promedioalumnos` and insert them into alumnosdestacados when `promedio>=90`. However, MySQL workbench gives me the following errors: `Syntax error: missing semicolon` in the values sentence and `Syntax error: 'end' is not valid in this position` in the end of sentence.

```
   create trigger alumnosdestacados after insert on promedioalumnos
   for each row
   if new.promedio >=90 then 
   insert into estudiantesdestacados 
   values (new.idalumno, new.promedio); 
   end if;
```

Comment: Hi, iterate "for each row" over what is iterating?. maybe not is necessary  this if  is triggered when you add a one row.

Comment: You need to use the `DELIMITER` directive before creating the trigger, so that `;` doesn't end the statement.

Comment: Don't take this "wisdom" for granted. The delimiter is a required only for editors that can take more than one query. In the stored routine editor however it's not necessary. Only one statement (the routine) can be edited there. However, it looks as if that statement above is edited in a normal SQL editor (and hence needs the delimiter), as it is otherwise syntactically correct.